# How To compare the Value Of The Div In jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I would appreciate If somebody help here! . I want to compare the value of the div from the php array using jQuery.

I have a php array

```
$newarray=array('cat','cap','catm','cam','catp','camp');
```

i have assigned a class **'turn'** too all the php array members

```
foreach($newarray as $col){
        echo "<p class='turn'>".$col."</p>";    
}
```

Now I want to check the value of the div and compare that if value in the textbox is equal to arrays value or not.

I have given the myBox id to the div

and this is my jQuery Code

```
    $(".wordComb").click(function(){

    $(".turn").each(function(i,e){
myDivObj = $('#myBox').text();
        if(myDivObj == e)
        {
                alert("Wow !!");
        }
        else{
            alert("try Again !");
        }
    });

    });
```

Comment: `e` is the DOM element object, not the text inside the element.

Comment: e is the element which has a class turn

Comment: But you want to check if the value of an input is equal to one element of the array or what?

Comment: yes i want to check the value of a div is equal to one of the element of array or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (myDivObj == e) {
```

should be

```
if (myDivObj == $(e).text()) {
```

since `e` is the `p.turn` HTML-element

[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/petervanderwal/uzba4hz2/)

Comment: no need to wrap `e` in jQuery, just use the innerText DOM property: `e.innerText`

Comment: #myBox is a div it is not a textbox

Comment: Sometimes I forget you can manipulate the DOM with native JS ;)

Comment: @modgeek  in that case disregard my comment on ` $('#myBox').val();`

Comment: i have done with the same way but in both cases it is not working

Comment: @modgeek I've added a jsFiddle example. ~working, it gives multiple alerts as you can expect in whithin that each-block, one of it is 'Wow'.

Comment: why it is going inside the else block first?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110015/discussion-between-peter-van-der-wal-and-mod-geek).